# How to navigate and get a specific json object in URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I getting a json from a url but it has lots of objects, how would I only get the slugs giving the json provided below?

I don't mind it either in php or js, I mean on the one hand I need to know how to get what object I want using php or js, on the other hand I am wondering if we can get an object providing a parameter in the url

```
[  
   {  
      "id":580,
      "count":0,
      "description":"qwer",
      "link":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/category\/persone\/414qwer1324r-qewr1233423\/",
      "name":"414qwer1324r qewr1233423",
      "slug":"414qwer1324r-qewr1233423",
      "taxonomy":"category",
      "parent":183,
      "meta":[  

      ],
      "_links":{  
         "self":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/580"
            }
         ],
         "collection":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"
            }
         ],
         "about":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"
            }
         ],
         "up":[  
            {  
               "embeddable":true,
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/183"
            }
         ],
         "wp:post_type":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=580"
            }
         ],
         "curies":[  
            {  
               "name":"wp",
               "href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
               "templated":true
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":586,
      "count":1,
      "description":"asdfasd",
      "link":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/category\/persone\/add-person\/",
      "name":"Add person",
      "slug":"add-person",
      "taxonomy":"category",
      "parent":183,
      "meta":[  

      ],
      "_links":{  
         "self":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/586"
            }
         ],
         "collection":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"
            }
         ],
         "about":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"
            }
         ],
         "up":[  
            {  
               "embeddable":true,
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/183"
            }
         ],
         "wp:post_type":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=586"
            }
         ],
         "curies":[  
            {  
               "name":"wp",
               "href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
               "templated":true
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":520,
      "count":8,
      "description":"",
      "link":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/category\/argomenti\/amici\/",
      "name":"AMICI",
      "slug":"amici",
      "taxonomy":"category",
      "parent":184,
      "meta":[
```

How would I get a list of all "slug":" with their value like "slug":"amici" in a url?

Like `http://example.com/ing/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/names`

Comment: Are you referring to the property in each object named `"slug"`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use `Array.prototype.map()` and destructuring assignment

```
let res = data.map(({slug}) => slug)
```

Comment: where would you define the URL and what Is it {slug}, didn't know about that

Comment: @rob.m What URL? What do you mean by "define"? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: yeah I mean the DATA, I need to get data from a url from another web site with REST api

Comment: @rob.m What data? This is the question at OP _"how would I only get the slugs giving the json provided below?"_

Comment: @rob.m Not following what you mean. The code at the answer gets all values of properties named `"slug"` and returns an `Array` containing those values

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and destructuring assignment

```js
let data = [{"id":580,"count":0,"description":"qwer","link":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/category\/persone\/414qwer1324r-qewr1233423\/","name":"414qwer1324rqewr1233423","slug":"414qwer1324r-qewr1233423","taxonomy":"category","parent":183,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/580"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/183"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=580"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}},{"id":586,"count":1,"description":"asdfasd","link":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/category\/persone\/add-person\/","name":"Addperson","slug":"add-person","taxonomy":"category","parent":183,"meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/586"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories"}],"about":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/category"}],"up":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories\/183"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/ing\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts?categories=586"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}]

let op = data.map(({slug})=> slug )

console.log(op)
```

Comment: what about all the slugs and not only one slug?

Comment: @rob.m what do you mean by that ? code here giving you all the value with key slug.

Comment: ehmm i try this on here but it only shows me [
  "414qwer1324r-qewr1233423",
  "add-person"
]

Comment: haha, sorry, had placed only part of the json! SO obviously there is only one haha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do it with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$slugs = array_column($posts, 'slug');
```

Comment: i mean are you suggesting to get the json as a url like $posts = myUrl and then run that?

Comment: You can try $posts[array_search('yourUrl', array_column($posts, 'slug'))] to get needed post. To decode your string to $posts array, use $posts = json_decode($_POST['posts'], true);